# Can't delete the namespace which is the MYSQL InnoDB Cluster installed in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, mysql-innodb-cluster

I installed a MYSQL Operator and a MYSQL InnoDB Cluster in deferent namespaces. Then I was about to delete both. It was successful for the MYSQL-Operator to delete. But I failed to delete the InnoDB Cluster. So I deleted each of the InnoDB Cluster components with force option. Some was successful but some was failed. So I tried to delete the namespace ifself with the last thing I could think of. But that ended up failure.
It would be great that someone help me solve this problem.
(Please let me know if you need more information.)

$ kubectl get namespace mycluster
mycluster   Terminating   5d1h

$ kubectl get all -n mycluster
No resources found in mycluster namespace

$ kubectl get namespace mycluster
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
annotations:
kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
{"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Namespace","metadata":{"annotations":{},"creationTimestamp":null,"name":"mycluster"},"spec":{},"status":{}}
creationTimestamp: "2024-01-13T01:14:56Z"
deletionTimestamp: "2024-01-13T02:30:18Z"
labels:
kubernetes.io/metadata.name: mycluster
name: mycluster
resourceVersion: "5011759"
uid: a24383af-79b3-4e04-8ec0-fc049431d936
spec:
finalizers:

- kubernetes
  status:
  conditions:
- lastTransitionTime: "2024-01-13T02:30:25Z"
  message: All resources successfully discovered
  reason: ResourcesDiscovered
  status: "False"
  type: NamespaceDeletionDiscoveryFailure
- lastTransitionTime: "2024-01-13T02:30:25Z"
  message: All legacy kube types successfully parsed
  reason: ParsedGroupVersions
  status: "False"
  type: NamespaceDeletionGroupVersionParsingFailure
- lastTransitionTime: "2024-01-13T02:30:25Z"
  message: All content successfully deleted, may be waiting on finalization
  reason: ContentDeleted
  status: "False"
  type: NamespaceDeletionContentFailure
- lastTransitionTime: "2024-01-13T02:30:25Z"
  message: 'Some resources are remaining: innodbclusters.mysql.oracle.com has 1
  resource instances'
  reason: SomeResourcesRemain
  status: "True"
  type: NamespaceContentRemaining
- lastTransitionTime: "2024-01-13T02:30:25Z"
  message: 'Some content in the namespace has finalizers remaining: mysql.oracle.com/cluster
  in 1 resource instances'
  reason: SomeFinalizersRemain
  status: "True"
  type: NamespaceFinalizersRemaining
  phase: Terminating

$ kubectl describe namespace mycluster
Name:         argocd
Labels:       kubernetes.io/metadata.name=argocd
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Active

No resource quota.

No LimitRange resource.

Name:         cert-manager
Labels:       kubernetes.io/metadata.name=cert-manager
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Active

No resource quota.

No LimitRange resource.

Name:         db-cluster
Labels:       kubernetes.io/metadata.name=db-cluster
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Active

No resource quota.

No LimitRange resource.

Name:         default
Labels:       kubernetes.io/metadata.name=default
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Active

No resource quota.

No LimitRange resource.

Name:         dev
Labels:       kubernetes.io/metadata.name=dev
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Active

No resource quota.

No LimitRange resource.

Name:         ingress-nginx
Labels:       kubernetes.io/metadata.name=ingress-nginx
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Active

No resource quota.

No LimitRange resource.

Name:         kube-node-lease
Labels:       kubernetes.io/metadata.name=kube-node-lease
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Active

No resource quota.

No LimitRange resource.

Name:         kube-public
Labels:       kubernetes.io/metadata.name=kube-public
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Active

No resource quota.

No LimitRange resource.

Name:         kube-system
Labels:       kubernetes.io/metadata.name=kube-system
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Active

No resource quota.

No LimitRange resource.

Name:         mycluster
Labels:       kubernetes.io/metadata.name=mycluster
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Terminating
Conditions:
Type                                         Status  LastTransitionTime               Reason                Message

NamespaceDeletionDiscoveryFailure            False   Sat, 13 Jan 2024 11:30:25 +0900  ResourcesDiscovered   All resources successfully discovered
NamespaceDeletionGroupVersionParsingFailure  False   Sat, 13 Jan 2024 11:30:25 +0900  ParsedGroupVersions   All legacy kube types successfully parsed
NamespaceDeletionContentFailure              False   Sat, 13 Jan 2024 11:30:25 +0900  ContentDeleted        All content successfully deleted, may be waiting on finalization
NamespaceContentRemaining                    True    Sat, 13 Jan 2024 11:30:25 +0900  SomeResourcesRemain   Some resources are remaining: innodbclusters.mysql.oracle.com has 1 resource instances
NamespaceFinalizersRemaining                 True    Sat, 13 Jan 2024 11:30:25 +0900  SomeFinalizersRemain  Some content in the namespace has finalizers remaining: mysql.oracle.com/cluster in 1 resource instances

No resource quota.

No LimitRange resource.

Name:         mysql-operator
Labels:       kubernetes.io/metadata.name=mysql-operator
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Active

No resource quota.

No LimitRange resource.

Name:         redis
Labels:       kubernetes.io/metadata.name=redis
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Active

No resource quota.

No LimitRange resource.

I tried to delete the namespace in many ways.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

```
kubectl patch crd mysqlbackups.mysql.oracle.com -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers": []}}' --type=merge
```

I patched crd's finalizers.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue but the above solution didn't work for me.

```
Labels:       kubernetes.io/metadata.name=mysql-operator
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Terminating
Conditions:
  Type                                         Status  LastTransitionTime               Reason                Message
  ----                                         ------  ------------------               ------                -------
  NamespaceDeletionDiscoveryFailure            False   Mon, 29 Jan 2024 14:12:46 +0530  ResourcesDiscovered   All resources successfully discovered
  NamespaceDeletionGroupVersionParsingFailure  False   Mon, 29 Jan 2024 14:12:46 +0530  ParsedGroupVersions   All legacy kube types successfully parsed
  NamespaceDeletionContentFailure              False   Mon, 29 Jan 2024 14:12:46 +0530  ContentDeleted        All content successfully deleted, may be waiting on finalization
  NamespaceContentRemaining                    True    Mon, 29 Jan 2024 14:12:46 +0530  SomeResourcesRemain   Some resources are remaining: innodbclusters.mysql.oracle.com has 1 resource instances
  NamespaceFinalizersRemaining                 True    Mon, 29 Jan 2024 14:12:46 +0530  SomeFinalizersRemain  Some content in the namespace has finalizers remaining: mysql.oracle.com/cluster in 1 resource instances

arun@ArunLAL555:/mnt/f/mysql-operator/innodb-cluster$ kubectl patch crd mysqlbackups.mysql.oracle.com -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers": []}}' --type=merge
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/mysqlbackups.mysql.oracle.com patched (no change)
arun@ArunLAL555:/mnt/f/mysql-operator/innodb-cluster$ kubectl patch crd kopfpeerings.zalando.org -p '{"
metadata":{"finalizers": []}}' --type=merge
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/kopfpeerings.zalando.org patched (no change)
arun@ArunLAL555:/mnt/f/mysql-operator/innodb-cluster$ kubectl patch crd clusterkopfpeerings.zalando.org -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers": []}}' --type=merge
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/clusterkopfpeerings.zalando.org patched (no change)
arun@ArunLAL555:/mnt/f/mysql-operator/innodb-cluster$ k get ns
NAME                  STATUS        AGE
actions-runner        Active        6d2h
mysql-operator        Terminating   4d8h
pet-clinic-app        Active        18d
pet-clinic-db         Active        19d
prometheus-operator   Active        37d
prometheus-thanos     Active        27d
stateful-workloads    Active        9d
thanos                Active        27d
```

The above solution works, you can try the following removing finalizers method to remove the stuck Namespaces on the Terminating state

```
for ns in $(kubectl get ns --field-selector status.phase=Terminating -o jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}')
do
  kubectl get ns $ns -ojson | jq '.spec.finalizers = []' | kubectl replace --raw "/api/v1/namespaces/$ns/finalize" -f -
done

for ns in $(kubectl get ns --field-selector status.phase=Terminating -o jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}')
do
  kubectl get ns $ns -ojson | jq '.metadata.finalizers = []' | kubectl replace --raw "/api/v1/namespaces/$ns/finalize" -f -
done
```

This will automatically identify the namespaces which are in the terminating state and manipulate the finalizer to empty them.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**